# how to write html code to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name=myform>
<input type=button value="Try it now" 
onClick="
s=prompt('Enter your first name','Name');
n=prompt('Enter your first name','Name');
document.write('hello'+s +n+' !')">
</form>
</body>
</html> '
```

In the above code, I would like to replace 'hello' with the code below. 
In the place of hello put this code:
`<div class="hreview">
<span class="item">
      Reviewed by  <span class="reviewer">john paul</span>
   Rating: 
   <span class="rating">5</span>
</div>`

it should display the code with out formatting the code what i had write in the place of hello.

Comment: document.write('<div class="hreview"> <span class="item"> Reviewed by <span class="reviewer">'+ n +'</span> Rating: <span class="rating">'+ s +'</span> </div>');

Comment: btw , Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet. :)

Comment: i.e. They are not the same. Java is a completely different language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **escape** your quotes like this:

```
document.write("<div class=\"hreview\"> <span class=\"item\"> Reviewed by <span class=\"reviewer\">john paul</span> Rating: <span class=\"rating\">5</span> </div>")
```

or use **single quotes**:

```
document.write("<div class='hreview'> <span class='item'> Reviewed by <span class='reviewer'>john paul</span> Rating: <span class='rating'>5</span> </div>")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use document.write() after the page has loaded, it can be used to add content to page while the DOM is getting prepared.

Eg:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="javascript">
 document.write('<h1>Mypage</h1>');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In your case the page has already been parsed and converted to [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/About_the_Document_Object_Model) , so you should directly change the DOM to reflect any change on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function getDetails(){
         var s=prompt('Enter your first name','Name');
         var n=prompt('Enter your first name','Name');
         document.body.innerHTML = ('hello'+s +n+' !');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name=myform>
<input type=button value="Try it now" 
onClick="getDetails()">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can read about DOM traversal

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are trying to use the `s` and `n` variables as first and last name in the updated html you are writing to the document, so that's what I've done here:

html:

```
<form name="myform">
    <input type="button" value="Try it now" onclick="write_message();" />
</form>
<span id="message"></span>
```

js:

```
function write_message() {
        var s=prompt('Enter your first name','First name');
        var n=prompt('Enter your last name','Last name');
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML='<div class="hreview"> <span class="item"> Reviewed by <span class="reviewer">'+s+' '+n+'</span> Rating: <span class="rating">5</span> </div>';
}
```

Also, as a tip, you've got a number of issues with your html. `inputs` should be closed properly as above with the slash at the end. Any attribute with a string for a value needs to be in quotes, and all html is lowercase, including `onclick`.